# Improve Bottleneck Performance in ASP.NET [core] System

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, stream

We are developing a System based on both ASP.NET and ASP.NET Core 3.1.
Recently, when doing improvements based on Load Tests, we discovered an API-Endpoint which handles both File-Uploads and some JSON Payload (it is a multipart request).

While it isn't surprising that this endpoint is the bottleneck, I think there is some room for improvement.

### Hot Path

The critical path appears to be the File-Upload Management.
Up to 25 Files can be uploaded (our load test send one 2MB File since this is the average).

The endpoint takes the `IFormFile`s, and assigns its Stream-Contents to a `byte[]` property of a DTO which then gets sent to another service based on .NET (not core) because it needs thje SharePoint SDK which does not support .NET Core :(.

Said service reads the `byte[]` into a Stream which gets sent to SharePoint where the documents are finally stored.

### My Question

I guess (no clue tbh) that the **Request** → `IFormFile.Stream` → `byte[]` → `Stream` → **SharePoint** chain could be realized without the conversion to and from `byte[]`.

Is this possible and if so: would it improve the performance of the overall operation?
In other words: is it possible to *stream* contents of an `IFormFile` through another Request to an intermediate WebService? (and would that make sense)

Comment: Have you done any profiling to check where the bottleneck is? I would expect conversion from/to a stream to be at most a copy, and just copying bytes is reasonably fast.

Comment: Right, but from what I've read, IFormFile Buffers the whole File in Memory which might explain why this is so slow. If we execute our Load Tests suite and skip just the upload part (still using the same endpoint), it is as fast as one could wish. That's why I think this is the problem. Profiling is kind of hard, because the Problem arises under "heavy load" exclusivley. When the app is idling, the load test scenarion executes said operation within under 1 second. Under Load its about 30s avg. up to over 60s (timeout).

Comment: Also, excuting the load scenario which is slow using sharepoint with a local mock (which writes to disk instead of sending it to our sharepoint service, it is reasonably fast even under load. maybe sharepoint it self is the problem here. Hard to investigate tbh.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question:
The problem was creating Folders in SharePoint (done once for every new Record with attached files).

It is slow as . (when under load)

We solved it by implementing an BackgroundJob that pre-creates a certain amount of folders in SharePoint nightly in advance, so that this step is not nessecary when handling the requests.